# boto3 session not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using `boto3` session to upload file to `s3`. I'm able to upload the file into s3 using using `~/.aws/credentials` but if i try to create a session as stated [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html), i get a forbidden error. Basically, i'm unable to upload using my credentials. The code is:

```
        if env == 'qa':
         credentials = getQaConfig(data)
         ACCESS_KEY = credentials['AccessKeyId']
         SECRET_KEY = credentials['SecretAccessKey']
        elif env == 'prod':
         credentials = getProdConfig(data)
         ACCESS_KEY = credentials['AccessKeyId']
         SECRET_KEY = credentials['SecretAccessKey']
       elif env == 'dev':
        credentials = getDevConfig(data)
        ACCESS_KEY = credentials['AccessKeyId']
        SECRET_KEY = credentials['SecretAccessKey']

      s3 = boto.Session(
           aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
           aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
           ).resource('s3')
```

Even if don't get the access key from environment and hardcode it directly, as shown below, i get an error.

```
      s3 = boto.Session(
           aws_access_key_id='my_Actual_key',
           aws_secret_access_key='mey actual_Secret
           ).resource('s3')
```

Comment: Post the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

The actual way of setting up S3 client with boto3 is as follows:

```
client = boto3.client(
's3',
aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)
```

Or via the Session

```
session = boto3.Session(
aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)
```

One possible reason of not being able to establish a session might be your accounts have SSO (Single Sign On) setup for AWS, and you need to parse the token along with remaining credentials